# Error in my Web API C# using Entity Framework with SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have an API in C#. My code is running fine off line but when I up to my server on 1 and 1 I received this error message:

> Message: "An error has occurred."
>
> ExceptionMessage: "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'ValuesController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.",
>
> ExceptionType: "System.InvalidOperationException",
>
> StackTrace:
>
> at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
>   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)
>   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()",
>
> InnerException: {
>   Message: "An error has occurred."
>   ExceptionMessage: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
>   ExceptionType: "System.NullReferenceException"
>
> StackTrace:
>   at api4food.DataClasses1DataContext..ctor() in C:\Users\joao\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\api4food\api4food\DataClasses1.designer.cs:line 39
>   at lambda_method(Closure)
>   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)

Comment: Probably beneficial to post your code, so we can see where (and why) it's failing. Error already tells you what the issue is: `Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.",`. OR, your line 39 has a null exception being presented

Comment: public DataClasses1DataContext() : 
    base(global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bd4foodConnectionString"].ConnectionString, mappingSource)
  {
   OnCreated();
  }

follow the snippet code, line 39