# API REST with Entity Framework and SQL server does not work when I move up to my 1an1 server

Tags: c#, linq

I am developing an API using Entity framework and SQL server, my local application runs perfectly but when I made the configuration of a new connection string and I uploaded my files to the 1and 1 server my code started to return the following code. Can someone help me?

> { Message: "An error has occurred.", ExceptionMessage: "An error
>   occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   'ValuesController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless
>   public constructor.", ExceptionType:
>   "System.InvalidOperationException", StackTrace: " at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage
>   request) at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()",
>   InnerException: { Message: "An error has occurred.", ExceptionMessage:
>   "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
>   ExceptionType: "System.NullReferenceException", StackTrace: " at
>   api4food.DataClasses1DataContext..ctor() in
>   C:\Users\joao\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2017\Projects\api4food\api4food\DataClasses1.designer.cs:line 39 at
>   lambda_method(Closure ) at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType)" } }

My Class Routeconfig.cs

```
namespace api4food
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

        }
    }
}`
```

My Class WebApiConfiguration

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.Indent = true;

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

myConectionString

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=dbxxxxxx.db.1and1.com,1433;Initial Catalog=db689804355;User Id=dboxxxxxx;Password=xxxxx;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>!
```

My Controller

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public ValuesController() 
    {
    }

    DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();

    // GET api/getallUsers
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/getall")]

    public List<classUser> Get()
    {
        List<classUser> userList = new List<classUser>();
        var user = from tb_User in dc.tb_User
                   select tb_User;
        foreach (var item in user)
        {
            classUser us = new classUser();
            us.ID = item.ID;
            us.name = item.name;
            us.email = item.email;
            us.bio = item.bio;
            userList.Add(us);
        }
        return userList;
    }


    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/get/{id:int}")]
    public classUser Get(int id)
    {
        classUser us = new classUser();
        var user = from tb_User in dc.tb_User
                   where tb_User.ID == id
                   select tb_User;
        foreach (var item in user)
        {
            us.ID = item.ID;
            us.name = item.name;
            us.email = item.email;
            us.bio = item.bio;
        }
        return us;
    }

    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/post")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]classUser usuario)
    {
        try
        {
            bool resultado = false;
            if (usuario == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("user can`t be null");
            // other code omitted
            // assuming tb_User has the same shape as classUser
            var usr = new tb_User
            {
                name = usuario.name,
                email = usuario.email,
                bio = usuario.bio
            };

            dc.tb_User.InsertOnSubmit(usr);
            dc.SubmitChanges();
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, resultado);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
        }
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("api/put")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Put(classUser usuario)
    {
        bool resultado = false;
        var user = from tb_User in dc.tb_User
                   where tb_User.ID == usuario.ID
                   select tb_User;
        foreach (var item in user)
        {
            item.name = usuario.name;
            item.email = usuario.email;
            item.bio = usuario.bio;
        }
            try
            {
                dc.SubmitChanges();
                resultado = true;
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, resultado);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(e);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e.Message);
            }

        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        [Route("api/delete/{id:int}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)

        {
            bool resultado = false;
            var itemDeleted = from result in dc.tb_User
                              where result.ID == id
                              select result;
            foreach (var item in itemDeleted)
            {
                dc.tb_User.DeleteOnSubmit(item);
            }
            try
            {
                dc.SubmitChanges();
                resultado = true;
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, resultado);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e.Message);
                // Provide for exceptions.
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the connection string names the same in the development environment and the 1and1 environment?  I'm assuming they are and you only changed the value in the "connectionString" attribute (Data Source, User ID, Password).  In the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45340333/error-in-my-web-api-c-sharp-using-entity-framework-with-sql-server) you posted yesterday, though, it looks like the connection string name was not "ApplicationServices" but rather "bd4foodConnectionString".

Is there a semi-colon in the 1and1 database password?  That could cause an issue parsing the connection string.

Comment: Yeah, you completely all right. Thank you so much. A little detail. I'm very grateful. :)